# Method return new object - Java

Tags: java

I wondering why does this code run this way.
In this example, the print output is 4. I was thinking that if the method2 were to return a new object should it not be 3 instead?

Hopefully someone can tell me what is happening. Thanks in advance!

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test test = new Test();
       test.method1();
    }

    private void method1() {
        try {
            TempItem item = new TempItem(5);
            method2(item);
            System.out.println(item.getValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    private TempItem method2(TempItem item) {
        item.setValue(4);
        return new TempItem(3);
    }

    class TempItem {

        int value = 2;

        public TempItem(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because you are not assigning the result of method2() in your main method.

Comment: ah i see thanks! so i have to assign item = method2(item), for it to work as intended?

Comment: hard to say what is intended - but the method is definitively returning `(3)`, which is not being used; but `item`, which is being printed, is still the one that got set to `(4)` (in the method)